# Make paperheight (page length) same as section length

Tags: sectioning, floats, page-breaking, paper-size

I'd like a document where each section is followed by a page-break but otherwise is *one* page. The sections have varying lengths, mainly due to the size of the picture(s) in each one.

So far what I have is:

```
\documentclass{article}
% make all pages long
\usepackage[paperheight=26in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref} % essential
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% from \documentclass{memoir}
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand*{\centerfloat}{%
   \parindent \z@
   \leftskip \z@ \@plus 1fil \@minus \textwidth
   \rightskip\leftskip
   \parfillskip \z@skip}
 \makeatother
% Redefine \section to add \clearpage at the beginning
\newcommand*{\OrgSection}{}
  \let\OrgSection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}{
  \clearpage
  \OrgSection
}
%
\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents
%\newpage
\section{First section}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}
\centerfloat
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth, height=12in]{demo}
\caption{Short caption}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{figure}
\centerfloat
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth, height=4in]{demo}
\caption{Short caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]

This is not intended to be printed. Many of the figures are longer than a standard page, but not all. I'm trying to avoid excessive whitespace. I would also prefer to avoid the figures 'floating' into another section.

The above solution works but the pages are too long in some cases. I'm trying to avoid having to redefine `[paperheight]` manually for each section as there are >40.

I'm open to other design suggestions here.

As still rather new to this so would be great if a solutions requiring `\makeatletter` had a little explanation.

I have been looking at the test package [screenread](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/screenread/) which is close to what I want, except that some of my figures are also slightly wider than standard textwidth and this is not supported by the above. Also in the above the default magnification of the .pdf viewer changes depending on section length, which is also not ideal...

Comment: Do you have figures that, together with the section heading will not fit on a page? If so, what do should happen to the figure? Do you want to increase the page size until it fits?

Comment: @dardisco: A tiny tipp: If you want to want to react to somebody's comment, you should use @ and the username (here `@Werner`) in a comment too. As far as I know, this @-message 'system' does not work within the original posts

Comment: @Werner - yes. Figures are too long for a 'standard' page so I would like the page length to 'stretch'. Should stretch to incorporate multiple figures if necessary. I have made the default 24 inches, but this is too long for certain figures.

Comment: @dardisco: See [How do comment @ replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/168244)

Comment: It sounds like your main concern is forcing `table` and `figure` floats to stay together with the sections in which they are mentioned via `\ref` or a related cross-referencing command. If that's the case, consider providing the command `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` in the preamble. This will force any and all pending floats to be typeset whenever a `\section` command is encountered.

Comment: @Mico thanks this is a good start. The figures (+captions) are of variable length; many are too long for standard page but if I set a long page as in the example then there's a lot of empty whitespace...

Comment: @dardisco - IMNSHO, captions should be short and self-explanatory. Important explanatory text should go in the main part of the text, not inside the float. If this works for you, the heights of your floats might be made less than `\textheight`, probably easing all kinds of problems related to the placement of the floats.

Comment: Are there any news here? I guess those pages shall never be printed, right? ;-) Are you by any chance making an screen-view only document, maybe even an e-book?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `\@makecol` macro in the output routine so it reboxes the page to its natural height rather than forcing it to be text height, then set `\pdfpageheight` to the height of that box (plus some extra for the 1in offset TeX uses, and the page margins).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% make all pages long
\usepackage[paperheight=26in,top=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref} % essential
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% from \documentclass{memoir}
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand*{\centerfloat}{%
   \parindent \z@
   \leftskip \z@ \@plus 1fil \@minus \textwidth
   \rightskip\leftskip
   \parfillskip \z@skip}


\let\old@makecol\@makecol
\def\@makecol{\old@makecol
 \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\unvbox\@outputbox}%
 \pdfpageheight=\dimexpr\ht\@outputbox+\dp\@outputbox+1.5in\relax}

 \makeatother

 \let\OrgSection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}{%
  \clearpage
  \OrgSection
}

%
\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents
%\newpage
\section{First section}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}
\centerfloat
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth, height=12in]{demo}
\caption{Short caption}
\end{figure}
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{figure}
\centerfloat
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth, height=4in]{demo}
\caption{Short caption}
\end{figure}
\section{Thirdsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```